# C format specifier question

Tags: c++, c, unix, printf

While I was working i came across a code which was written by somebody else.
 i see a statement as ,

```
sprintf(o_params->o_file_name,
        "%s_%s_%04.4d_%s_%s.ASC",
        "OUTD", "RM", sequence_no, DateStamp_buf1, TimeStamp_buf1
);
```

In the above statement, I see `%04.4d`. Is this  a correct format specifier?

The variable `sequence_no` is `static int` and it doesn't have decimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [FreeBSD manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=printf&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE&format=html) `man 3 printf`

> An optional precision, in the form of
>   a period . followed by an  optional
>   digit string.  If the digit string is
>   omitted, the precision  is taken as
>   zero.  **This gives the minimum number
>   of digits to appear  for d, i, o, u,
>   x, and X conversions**, the number of
>   digits to appear  after the
>   decimal-point for a, A, e, E, f, and F
>   conversions, the  maximum number of
>   significant digits for g and G
>   conversions, or the  maximum number of
>   characters to be printed from a string
>   for s conversions.

So in this case, `%04.4d`, the `.4` specifies that all four digits of the number should be printed. Of course, the `04` part just pads the number with leading zeros if it is less than 1000. However, in this case, as the above manual page states,

> `0' (zero)   Zero padding.  For all conversions except n, the converted
>   value is padded on the left with zeros rather
>   than blanks.
>   **If a precision is given with a numeric
>   conversion (d, i, o, u, i, x, and X), the 0 flag is
>   ignored**.

Since surely all four digits would be printed anyway, my guess would be that it was just a leftover or typo or something. This syntax produces compiler warnings with `gcc -Wall` (see Sinan Unur's example) but it does not seem to be an actual error.

Comment: Yes,this is what my doubt was...if %04d is serving the same purpose why that .4 is added to it?

Comment: +1 for noting that "%04.4d" is more than necessary. In fact, the "0" is ignored: From the sprintf man page: "If a precision is given with a numeric conversion (d, i, o, u, x, and X), the 0 flag is ignored."

Answer (score 1):

"dot whatever" specifies the precision. According to sprintf's man page, this means the following for ints (d):

> The precision, if any, gives the minimum number of digits that  must
>   appear;  if  the  converted  value  requires fewer digits, it is
>   padded on the left with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

`%d` is the format specifier for integers in [`printf`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sprintf/):

> The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:

```
diouxX  The int (or appropriate variant) argument is converted to signed
        decimal (d and i), unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal (u), or
        unsigned hexadecimal (x and X) notation.  The letters ``abcdef''
        are used for x conversions; the letters ``ABCDEF'' are used for X
        conversions.  The precision, if any, gives the minimum number of
        digits that must appear; if the converted value requires fewer
        digits, it is padded on the left with zeros.
```

Assuming, @Kinopiko's interpretation is correct, here is the distinction between `%4d` versus `%4.4d` (also showing why `%04.4d` is not needed and the appropriate warning being emitted by `gcc`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int t = 123;
    printf("%%04.4d:\t" "%04.4d\n", t);
    printf("%%4.4d:\t"   "%4.4d\n", t);
    printf("%%04d:\t"     "%04d\n", t);
    printf("%%4d:\t"       "%4d\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

```
C:\Temp> gcc z.c -o z.exe -Wall
z.c: In function 'main':
z.c:5: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%d' printf format
z.c:5: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%d' printf format

C:\Temp> z
%04.4d: 0123
%4.4d:  0123
%04d:   0123
%4d:     123
```

Comment: No, he's asking why there is a `.4` after the `%04`.

Answer (score 0):

look here: [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/)

.number: For integer specifiers (d, i, o, u, x, X): precision specifies the minimum number of digits to be written ...

It is valid.

Answer (score 0):

%04.4d means the corresponding argument is an int, and it should be printed with leading zeros with field width 4 and precision 4.

It appears correct to me (assuming that the output looks the way you want).

Comment: Yes,I agree but why  .4 is added to it since 04d serves the same pupose giving the same output.

Answer (score 0):

%04.4d looks valid to me. Is it not just a decimal with 4 characters width and 4 precision?

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

See here

[link text](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: if %04d is serving the same purpose why that .4 is added to it?

Comment: Thanks Kinopiko, fixed the typo