# Objective C: For loop with images image0001.png

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have images called:

image0001.png
image0002.png 
... 
image0234.png...

How do I make the for loop under stand how many "0" there should be?

```
 //this code crash
for (int i = 0; i < 234; i++)
{
    [myImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image000%i", i]]]; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but `i < 10` has three 0s, `10 <= i < 100` has two 0s, and the rest have one 0. Mikhail's answer follows this idea. But the question eldarerathis mentioned also has a good solution and is worth looking into.

Comment: This approach should work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594582/c-format-specifier-question

Comment: Take: http://stackoverflow.com/a/964373/1130894. This is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: you have to start int i = 1 and i <= 234

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    [myImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image000%i", i]]]; 
}
for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++)
{

    [myImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image00%i", i]]]; 
}
for (int i = 100; i <= 234; i++)
{

    [myImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image0%i", i]]]; 
}
```

Comment: At lest do just one for and use several ifs to check if the value of i is inside the range you want. It's much better if the limit value of the for ever changes...

Comment: Why? Using "if" in this case  - redundant comparison operations

Comment: Why redundant? With nested if else it's not redundant and your for can grow for whatever values you want. It's the difference between code that works today and takes little effort to work tomorrow when requirements change...